# printing an array of strings using pointers only in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have defined a constant array of strings as

```
static const char *Props[] = {"Cp", "Cv", "Mu", "H"};
```

I get error while executing the following:

```
while(*Props) printf("%s\n", *Props++);
```

Error message is:

> C/test.c:38:45: error: lvalue required as increment operand

Can anybody please explain why I get this error?

Comment: The array itself is a constant. It can not be changed. `static const char *Props[] = {"Cp", "Cv", "Mu", "H", NULL};
 const char **p = Props;
 while(*p) printf("%s\n", *p++);`

Comment: But the program executes when I write
while(*Props) printf("%s\n", *(Props+1));
Why?

Comment: `Props+1` does not change `Props`. `Props+1` does not mean `Props = Props+1`

Answer (score 2):

Array designators are non-modifiable lvalues. You may not change them. What you need is the following

```
static const char *Props[] = {"Cp", "Cv", "Mu", "H"};

for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( Props ) / sizeof( *Props ); i++ )
{
    puts( Props[i] );
}
```

Another approach is to add a sentinel value to the array. For example

```
static const char *Props[] = {"Cp", "Cv", "Mu", "H", NULL };

for ( const char **s = Props; *s; s++ )
{
    puts( *s );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only for the purposes of satisfying the requirements of this odd question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void
print_props(void)
{
    static const char *Props[] = {"Cp", "Cv", "Mu", "H"};
    const char **b = Props;
    const char **e = Props + sizeof(Props)/sizeof(Props[0]);

    do {
        puts(*(b++));
    } while (b != e);
    return;
}

int
main(void)
{
    print_props();
    return 0;
}
```

However, just use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work work the same reason as `int array [] = {1,2}; array++;` doesn't work.

You can't apply `++` on an array type. You would need a pointer to the first item of the array instead. Thus one solution would have been to do this:

```
const char** ptr = &Props[0]; 
while(*ptr) printf("%s\n", *ptr++);
```

But that's pretty horrible code and also contains another bug, namely the lack of an end condition in the array. For this solution to work, the array  should have been declared as `{"Cp", "Cv", "Mu", "H", NULL};`.

Don't do weird things like this just because you can though. Just use a for loop with an integer iterator, as demonstrated in another answer.